# Memory leakage after throwing exception c++

Tags: c++, exception, memory-leaks, valgrind

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>

class OutOfMem { };
class IndexOutOfRange { };
class NoFile { };
class InvalidFileFormat { };
class WrongDim { };

class Array {
public:
    Array(double * arr, const unsigned c) : array(arr), columns(c) { }
    double &operator [] (const unsigned i) 
    { 
        if(i >= columns)
            throw IndexOutOfRange();
        return array[i];
    }
private:
    double * array = nullptr;
    unsigned columns;
};

class 2DArray {

public:
    2DArray(std::fstream &is)
    {
        if(!is)
            throw NoFile();
        if(!(is >> rows >> columns))
            throw InvalidFileFormat();
        matrix = new (std::nothrow) double *[rows];
        if(!matrix)
            throw OutOfMem();
        use = new (std::nothrow) std::size_t(1);
        if(!use)
            throw OutOfMem();
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            matrix[i] = new(std::nothrow) double[columns];
            if(!matrix[i])
                throw OutOfMem();
        }
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for(unsigned j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                double temp;
                if(!(is >> temp))
                    throw WrongDim();
                matrix[i][j] = temp;
            }

    }
    ~2DArray() 
    {
        if(--*use == 0)
        {
            for(unsigned i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                delete [] matrix[i];
            delete [] matrix;
            delete use;
        }
    }
    Array operator [] (const unsigned i)
    {
        if(i >= rows)
            throw IndexOutOfRange();
        if(*use == 1)
            return Array(matrix[i], columns);
        else
        {
            double ** copy;
            copy = new (std::nothrow) double *[rows];
            for(unsigned i = 0 ; i < rows; i++)
            {
                copy[i] = new (std::nothrow) double[columns]();
                if(!copy[i])
                    throw OutOfMem();
                for(unsigned j = 0 ; j < columns; j++)
                    copy[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
            }
            --*use;
            matrix = copy;
            use = new std::size_t(1);
            return Array(matrix[i], columns);
        }
    }
private:
    unsigned rows;
    unsigned columns;
    double ** matrix = nullptr;
    std::size_t * use;
};
```

I've got the problem with the program used for reading the matrix from the file but i've got memory leak during when I reformat the file adding incorrect value. The destructor should be called but somehow few objects remains still after throw. Any tips??
 I'm using valgrind for memory check.

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is your friend. `new` and `delete` are your enemies.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I know. Usually I really rarely use new and delete. But that was for assignment and i was obliged not to use containers.

Comment: Your constructor should use `istream` so it can take any input stream.

Comment: Is it part of the assignment to throw some exceptions? If not, ditch the exceptions. If so, tell your teacher he is teaching you worthless nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine what happens in `2DArray(std::fstream &is)` if this line fails:

```
use = new (std::nothrow) std::size_t(1);
```

You throw an `OutOfMem` exception, but you don't delete the memory allocated by `matrix` a few lines above. And you have plenty of such cases in your code.

You have two options:

1. Carefully check what is being allocated, catch exceptions in the constructor, delete what is needed and rethrow the exceptions. A useful strategy in this case is first to initialize everything to zero and in exception handler simply call `delete` on all pointers.
2. (Much more preferable) Use standard containers, such as `std::vector`, or at least smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` which will free you from the need to manually clean up memory.

Update: I forgot to point out what seemed obvious to me: if an exception is thrown from the constructor, the destructor is not called because the object was not constructed. And even if it was called, think about the disastrous consequences it would lead to in your case.

Comment: He is leaving the memory deallocation to the destructor, which isn't being called due to the fact that the object did not get constructed successfully.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your destructor is not being called is simply because if an exception is thrown in the constructor, the object is considered to be **not constructed**.

Thank you for reading.